# 5-digit numbers that have certain properties

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

This question is an AMC style question as I am practicing for it. The question is this: How many 5-digit numbers have all of the following properties?

1. All 5 digits are different
2. The first digit is from 2 through 6 inclusive
3. The last digit is from 3 through 7 inclusive
4. The middle digit is odd

I would like to know a quick way to do it.

Comment: Seems like a lot of case work, but it could be worse...  Pick the middle digit.  Break into cases based on if it was $3,5$, if it was $7$, or if it was $1,9$.  Pick the first digit.  Break into cases based on if it was a $2$ or not.  Note the number of choices changed based on what was picked for the middle digit.  Pick the last digit.  Note that the number of choices changed based on what was picked for the middle digit and whether or not $2$ was chosen for the first digit.  Finally, pick the remaining digits.  Apply rule of sum and product and conclude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What JMoravitz commented. Break it up into cases based on the middle digit.